# How to retrieve checkboxes values in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to retrieve checkbox value through jquery, here my checkbox value is coming from "ng-model" angularjs.
what i want to:
I want to retrieve value of checkbox and see whether its true or false and according to those value i want to addclass of bootstrap collapse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in order to access to your checkbox value que its status  change.

```
$(".EnableIdchck").change(function() {
   if(this.checked) {
    //Do stuff
   }else if (!this.checked){
   // Do other Staff
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just embrace Angular if you're already using it, and bind the same model to show or hide your chart div?  eg:

```
<div id='chrt' ng-show='Enable'>your content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-model with ng-class. I recommend to avoid mixing jquery and angular.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

//controllers declaration
app.controller('myCtrl1',function($scope){
  //do something
});
```

```css
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
.green{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp"> 

<div class="div1" ng-controller="myCtrl1"> 
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
    <span ng-class="checked?'red':'green'">Content</span> 
</div>  
</body>
```

Comment: I have one add new page in which if user select the checkbox the collapse work properly in add new page and if he/she click on save button the value store in DB. if he/she want to edit that page all the filled and selected value is coming expect the checkbox one and because that collapse class is also not coming so i want to checked the checkbox if user selected on addnew page and add collapse class to slide down the panel.

Comment: Selected checkbox value is not getting saved and not getting from db. right?